# How can I change the href attribute in the script section in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

I want to set the href attribute to item.AppUrl, which is coming from a database and is rendered in the methods section.

```
          <template v-if="header.value == 'ApplicationName'">
        <a id="url" href="#" target="_blank">{{renderData(props.item, header)}}</a>
      </template>

methods: {
  renderData: (item, header) => {
    if (header.value == 'ApplicationName') {
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("href", item.AppUrl);
    }
    let val = "";
    if (header.value.includes('.')) {
      +
    const vals = header.value.split('.')
      val = vals.reduce((acc, val) => acc[val], item)
    } else {
      val = item[header.value]
    }
    if (typeof val === "boolean") {
      val = val ? "Yes" : "No";
    }
    return val;
  }
}
```

Comment: Bind the href to the method. I.e, `:href="renderData(...)"`

Comment: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined"

Comment: That's coming from this line - `document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("href", item.AppUrl);`. Looks like you're trying to set it manually too.

Comment: I dont really know what to do then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the result of a method to the attribute. Below, the result of the function `getUrl()` is bound to the `href` attribute using `:` (this is shorthand for `v-bind:href`. When doing this, there's no need to try and set the attribute manually within the function.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   
  },
  methods: {
    getUrl: function(){
      // return any value to demonstrate how this works
      return "https://google.com";
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <a :href="getUrl()">This links to google</a>
</div>
```

Comment: the link from the line `return "https://meta.stackoveflow.com";` leads to some fishing website, I've just checked.  Please take actions.

Comment: @ferrum Was a typo in the url (missed the r). Swapped the link to google.

Comment: ok, it happens...